# Axios - How can I get a value in a nested JSON object?

Tags: json, axios

I'm using axios to get json data from an API and I want to get the `key` value inside `Aatrox` and all the other 'champions' the problem is that I don't want to put `champKEY = response.data.data.Aatrox.key;` because there are multiple objects like `Aatrox` that have their own `key`. For reference, I'm getting a value `key` from a different API and I'm trying to compare both `keys` to see what 'champion' is.

```
{
  "type": "champion",
  "format": "standAloneComplex",
  "version": "11.4.1",
  "data": {
    "Aatrox": {
      "version": "11.4.1",
      "id": "Aatrox",
      "key": "266",
      "name": "Aatrox",
      "title": "the Darkin Blade",
      "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
      "info": {<->},
      "image": {<->},
      "tags": [<->],
      "partype": "Blood Well",
      "stats": {<->}
    },
    "Ahri": {<->},
    "Akali": {<->},
```

This works, but it only gives me the key for `Aatrox`.

```
axios.get('http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/11.4.1/data/en_US/champion.json')
        .then((response) => {
           champKEY = response.data.data.Aatrox.key;
        });
```

Comment: That doesn't work because data and `Aatrox` are not arrays

Comment: It doesn't, I just tried that and got `undefined`

Comment: Check my last edit, maybe you got confused

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).